# Looking for better way of writing a code logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have the following code with a `CASE` statement:

```
--to check if any record with this conditon present in table
--then pick col1, if such record exists
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT col1 from table where col2=1 and col3 is not null)
    THEN (SELECT col1 from table where col2=1 and col3 is not null)  
ELSE
      <something else>
END
```

Condition in the where are many more and code looks so big. Can see repeting also in `WHEN` case and `THEN` case.

Any better way to rewrite the code. with no impact on performance

Comment: "Condition in the where are many more and code looks so big." If your query is much bigger than that, show us the whole query. This, however, seems like you could just use `ISNULL`: `ISNULL(({Your Subquery}), {Something else})`

Comment: how will i pick col1 value using ISNULL..can u elaborate the above suggestion

Comment: What do you mean "how will you *pick* Col1"? `SELECT Col1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the query you listed would work, is it part of a larger query? Part of a SET statement? I think what you're looking for may be pulling the SELECT outside your CASE, like this

```
;with cteSampleData as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Row 1', 1, NULL)
    ,('Row 2', 1, 'Also row 2')
    ,('Row 3', 2, NULL)
    ,('Row 4', 2, 'Also row 4')
    ,('Row 5', 1, 'Also row 5')
    ) as SampleData(Col1, Col2, Col3)
)SELECT SD.Col1, SD.Col2, SD.Col3, 
    CASE WHEN col2=1 and col3 is not null
        THEN col1
    ELSE
        CONCAT('Anything other than ', Col1)
    END as MyCase
FROM cteSampleData as SD
```

Note that in the query you wrote, you would potentially return multiple rows in your THEN clause, which I think is an error regardless of settings, but at least is an error in the default SQL Server configuration.